# VatNumber Validation using SOAP client

Tags: php

I'm having a problem in my script class, is giving me the error:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$client' (T_VARIABLE), expecting identifier (T_STRING)
```

But I can't figure out what is the problem with the "client Variable".

Answer (score 0):

> While accessing **constant** class members you need to use **self::**, but while
>   accessing local variable you can use simply by variable name.

So you need to use `self::client` instead of `$client`. Because `$client` is constant class member.

[**DEMO**](https://eval.in/450330) or [**See More Info**](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.constants.php)

Comment: Yes, your right, my bad, but is still giving me the error and line 10 the const $client var

Comment: I have updated my answer can you take a look.

Comment: thanks, this is a good point, i had no ideia, but is still giving me the error even after i updates the variable to self::client, it is giving me the error at the declaration of the $client

Comment: Other then this code seems fine have you included library for `SOAP`?